# Author attribution via command line option with GitHub handle?

Tags: github, git-commit, author

We find a number of folks provide bug reports and diffs, but don't make pull requests. I'd like to give them credit for their work in a commit even when they don't provide the pr.

Its not clear to me how to provide attribution because Git's ***`--author`*** option [seems to want an email address](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), and I'm not sure how that intersects with a GitHub handle. [GitHub | Commits Help](https://help.github.com/categories/commits/) does not discuss it, either.

How do I provide an author attribution via command line option with GutHub handle? Can I simply use ***`--author`***? Or do I need special syntax for GitHub handles?

---

It appears I cannot simply use a Git handle or a github based email (I should have known it could not be simple because its Git). It appears I have to force it :

```
$ git commit rdrand.cpp -m "Fix clobbered registers (Issue 124)" --author "Name xxx"
fatal: No existing author found with 'Name xxx'
```

I also tried:

```
$ git commit rdrand.cpp -m "Fix clobbered registers (Issue 124)" --author "GitHub xxx"
fatal: No existing author found with 'GitHub xxx'

$ git commit rdrand.cpp -m "Fix clobbered registers (Issue 124)" --author "GitHub:xxx"
fatal: No existing author found with 'GitHub:xxx'
```

I even tried:

```
$ git commit rdrand.cpp -m "Fix clobbered registers (Issue 124)" --author "Name xxx@github.com"
fatal: No existing author found with 'Name xxx@github.com'
```

How do I force Git to accept the name?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, `--author` takes an author name/email in the format `Author Name <email@address.com>`. You can't specify a GitHub username. However, if you select an email address that the user has associated with their GitHub account, GitHub will show their username in their UI.

However, there are other ways to get the proper commit attribution if you want:

1. If they forked your repository, you can grab the commits from their fork and apply them to your repo, even if they don't make a pull request.
2. If they don't have or don't want to use GitHub and prefer to send a patch, have them prepare a patch using `git format-patch` and apply it using `git am`.

Comment: Thanks @mipadi. I don't think (1) or (2) applies. They did not fork; and they did not offer a patch or pr.

Comment: @jww: If they're not authoring the changes at all, I'd just make the changes as yourself and make a note in the commit body that the work is based on a suggestion or bug report by So-and-So.